# How to establish connection between EC2 and RDS sitting in different vpc's using vpc endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have ec2 provisioned in vpc A in the public subnet and rds provisioned in vpc B in the public subnet, the instance accesses rds through an internet gateway secured by security groups. since both the vpc have the same overlapping CIDR range, I can't able to create vpc peering.

Is there a way to establish connectivity with VPC endpoints?

i would like the traffic from ec2 should flow through the endpoint to rds across VPC, instead of reaching the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AWS PrivateLink. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/access-amazon-rds-across-vpcs-using-aws-privatelink-and-network-load-balancer/

Comment: Thanks for your response, working on that